# How to discriminate possible error reasons of PHP's copy (and where to find them)?

Tags: php, runtime-error

**Note** I don't understand how this is still marked as duplicate. I've understood that `$errno` [has nothing to do](https://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) with the error reason and modified the question to highlight that I'm looking for that and not for interpreting `$errno` values.

---

I'm trying to make error messages (that happen on attempt to backup) more helpful for users.

I know that I can do

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    http_response_code(500);
    exit("error when trying to make a backup copy: errno is $errno, errstr is $errstr");
});
$success = copy($fileToBackup, $backupPath);
restore_error_handler();
```

but, for instance, I'd like to hide the root folder of the project, hence I'd like to provide something custom instead of `$errstr`. Also I probably want different http codes for different errors. Is there a list of possible error reasons and a way to discriminate them (aside analysing `$errstr`)? I understand that theoretically I can find those by digging PHP sources, but that's.. not exactly nice and quick way of developing things.

Comment: `$errno` will be one of these: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: @deceze oh, so they are not exactly reason-specific.. Thanks! So discriminating all error reasons with different handling is only possible by analysing the `$errstr`, right?

Comment: "I'd like to hide the root folder of the project" - what does that mean? What have you tried to do that?

Comment: @NicoHaase that means that I'd like not not show the absolute path of the project, only relative paths inside it

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve that? Simple string replacement could help?

Comment: @NicoHaase why, that's not the point of the question. I'm looking for the list of possible error reasons and not for dealing with one specific case.

Comment: To find out all possible errors you don't have to dig out the PHP sources. Rather, the sources of the Operating System it runs on

Comment: @YourCommonSense, right, this means that the only viable approach is probably to distinguish and process some known ones. The second part of the question is – is there any better way to discriminate them than analysing `$errstr`?

Comment: Nope, there is not.